# How to encrypt Paypal button in Java

Tags: java, encryption, button, paypal

I'm looking for a good example/class that would take my certificates in argument, and generate the signed button to use for paypal.

I find that link https://www.paypal.com/us/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=p/xcl/rec/ewp-code that contain a Java class using BouncyCastle, but when importing the new version of BouncyCastle, some part of the Paypal code are deprecated and I don't know how to change them.

I also find an alternative to BouncyCastle, [Keyczar](http://www.keyczar.org/), but I can't find any example on how to encrypt the paypal button.

Thank you for your help!

Comment: you shouldnt be writing the code yourself. use paypal's tools to generate the code for you then copy-paste it into your site

Comment: I can't generate the code for each button because this is a generic process My users should be able to add their product for sale.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have written a button generator in Java for a project, you can find the code [here](http://code.google.com/p/jppal/).

It's also using bouncy castle, but it's a fairly recent version. It also uses velocity to generate the button code based on a template (included).

Comment: Thanks. Yours also use a deprecated method of Bouncy Castle, but it doesn't matter if it works ;)

Comment: Your link to your Java Project doesn't provide a download for the code. I would be interested in a button generator for Java as well. Just going through the Paypal site trying to learn how to automatically create buttons is getting me nowhere...

Comment: I have added zips to download, I'm working on an sample webapp, but It's not ready yet